# How to get pointer value in parse.com and Android platforms?

Tags: android, pointers, parse-platform

I am working on the parse.com and Android platforms. In my _User table I have a Pointer Column `Info<pointer>`, I want to get the value of that column. For other columns I can easily get the values like:

```
final ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

String currentUserId = user.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
    String currentUserFirstName = user.getString("firstName");
    String currentUserLastName = user.getString("lastName");
    String currentUserEmail = user.getCurrentUser().getEmail();
```

But when I do the same thing for `info<pointer Value>` column I don't get any value:

```
String infoPointer = user.getString("info");
```

Comment: "info" column is a Pointer to another class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have just solved my problem. It works by using CallBackMethod:

```
public static ParseObject user= new ParseObject("UserInfo");
user.getParseObject("info").fetchIfNeededInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {

        @Override
        public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ParseObject userinfo = object;
            String doctor = userinfo.getString("door");
            String allergies = userinfo.getString("algies");
            String medicalNote = userinfo.getString("mediote");
            String medications = userinfo.getString("medic");
            String medicalCondition = userinfo.getString("medicalCondition");

            docInfo.setText(doctor);
            medication.setText(medications);
            medNotes.setText(medicalNote);
            medCond.setText(medicalCondition);
            alergiesReact.setText(allergies);

            Log.i("userinfo", "" + userinfo);
        }
    });
```